# How to rewrite a Sum?

Tags: summation

How to find the following sum?
$$
\frac{2}{n}  \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{4i}{n} +1\right)
$$
For example
$$
\sum_{i = 1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.
$$
I need to find the value of which this would converge to and I know that it must be six because the integral from $1$ to $3$ of the function $(2x-1)$ is $6$.

Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: $\sum i = (n)(n+1)/2$ ?

Comment: A couple of hints: A constant can always be moved in front of the summation, like this:
$$
\sum_n {a f(n)} = a \sum_n f(n)
$$
And the sum is also distributive:
$$
\sum_{n} (a_n + b_n) = \sum_n a_n + \sum_n b_n
$$

Comment: @Matti Infinite sum also? distributive?

Comment: Sorry, I meant in a finite case, like this.

Answer (score 9):

**Hint:**
You have to use $$\sum_{i=1}^n (a_i+b_i) = \left(\sum_{i=1}^na_i\right)+\left(\sum_{i=1}^n b_i\right)$$
and
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n (\lambda a_i)=\lambda\left(\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\right)
$$
For the second equation, you have to check that $\lambda$ can not depend on $i$ but it can depend on other variables like $n$.

Comment: Mundron - Why can we directly split this sum, for infinite case its not allowed right

Comment: It comes from the associative and distributive law. But in general, you can't use it for infinite sums.

Answer (score 2):

$$\frac{2}{n}  \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left(\frac{4i}{n} +1\right) = \frac{2}{n}\left( \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{4i}{n} + \sum_{i=1}^{n} 1\right) = \frac{8}{n^2}\sum_{i=1}^{n} i + \frac{2}{n}\cdot n =  \frac{8}{n^2}\cdot \frac{n(n+1)}{2} + 2 = 4 \left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right) + 2$$

Comment: The final result could have been simplified.

Comment: I wanted to put at least one little challenge to the OP. :-)